# Python & db browser : cannot insert data from a table in another one

Tags: python, database, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I have a little project and I don't understand how to resolve it. 
I want to create a pc builder for a school project with Tkinter and SQLite 3 (that's the rules). But I have a huge issue : When i want to save informations into the database, nothing is putting on. \

Here is the configurator. Before this UI there was another one for register. And it works :
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEJbq.jpg) \

After you have this screen. Every PC parts are inside other tables from the same db.
[Configurator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aYkh.png)

When you hit configuration, it's the problem. As you can see in the database, nothing is putting on. Every PC parts are inside tables. Like one table for mobo, one for processors, etc.
Please may someone knows why it don't work? \

I share the part code where i get informations

```
enter code here
global nomGet, prenomGet, emailGet, ageGet, get_processeur, get_carteM, get_ram, get_carteG, get_disqueDur, get_Alim, get_ventilo, get_boitier 

nom = nomGet.get()
prenom = prenomGet.get()
email = emailGet.get()
age = ageGet.get()
choix_processeur = get_processeur.get()
choix_carte_mere = get_carteM.get()
choix_ram = get_ram.get()
choix_carte_graph = get_carteG.get()
choix_disque_dur = get_disqueDur.get()
choix_alim = get_Alim.get()
choix_ventilo = get_ventilo.get()
choix_boitier = get_boitier.get()
conn = sqlite3.connect("DB_ConfigOrdi.db")
curseur = conn.cursor()
curseur.execute("INSERT INTO Clients ( `Nom`, `Prenom`, `Email`, `Age`, `Proc`, `CM`, `Memoire`, `CarteGraph` , `HDD`, `Alim`, `Ventilation`, `Case`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (nom, prenom, email, age, choix_processeur, choix_carte_mere, choix_ram, choix_carte_graph, choix_disque_dur, choix_alim, choix_ventilo, choix_boitier ))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Do you get any error when you run? Are you sure that you are connecting to the specific database file?

Comment: i don't have any error at all when i run. It just don't put nothing in the database.
How I can be sure if it's fully linked ? I can share the full code if it's necessary